# JFR recording analysis: Path in the File I/O report is "null"?

Tags: jvm, jfr

I'm profiling (using JFR's "Continuous" profile settings) a non-trivial production application which does a lot of I/O and I'm surprised that the File I/O report shows only a single row with Path ***null***.
How can I find out why is this happening and fix it?

It's a pretty standard java/clojure app and it runs in a docker container.

[image]

Comment: stdin, perhaps?

Comment: Well, this app is definitely reading and writing lots of files. So I'm really puzzled why it doesn't show anything (perhaps I should try to lower the "File I/O Threshold" but still)  Maybe "null" means stdin/stdout but that's a really odd name :).

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is the default "Continuous" profile - it's supposed to be used for our app in production (for that reason I'm also reluctant to change any default settings since I'm not sure what effect they might have)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the file stream was created using a file descriptor, for example System.out, System.in and System.err.

Comment: Thanks, that makes some sense. Although I'm wondering why it doesn't show any other File IO - perhaps all the other file operations were pretty fast? But then why could reading from stdout would be slow?

Comment: You can look at the stack trace. It will show you where the null path events were invoked. If events are missing, it's likely the threshold. In JDK 17, you can start with -XX:StartFlightRecording:file-threshold=0ns to get all events, but it could potentially be millions of events per second, so perhaps start with 1ms. In earlier releases, it's easiest to configure the threshold in JMC, in the Recording Wizard or Window -> Template Manager